# Symfony 4 redirectToRoute dont send parameters with Post method

Tags: symfony4

The redirectToRoute method don't send the parameters to the other route 
PS : i use the POST method

First route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/CheckAuthentification",name="security_authentification")
 */
public function authentification(Request $request)
{
    *
    *
    *
        return $this->redirectToRoute('profil', ['categories'=>$categories,'user'=>$user]);
   }
```

Second route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/Profil",name="Profil_page")
 */
public function profil($categories,$user)
{
    return $this->render('user/profil.html.twig',['categories'=>$categories,'user'=>$user]);
}
```

Error :

> Controller "App\Controller\ProfilController::profil()" requires that
>   you provide a value for the "$categories" argument. Either the
>   argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default
>   value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to send the objects in the session
First route :

```
$this->container->get('session')->set('user', $user);
$this->container->get('session')->set('categories', $categories);
return $this->redirectToRoute('profil');
```

Second route :

```
$user = $this->container->get('session')->get('user');
$categories = $this->container->get('session')->get('categories');
return $this->render('user/profil.html.twig',['categories'=>$categories,'user'=>$user]);
```